# The Schur property and containing no isomorphic copy of $l_{1}$

Tags: banach-spaces

Recall that a Banach space $X$ is said to have the Schur property if any weakly null sequence in $X$ is norm null, equivalently, every weakly Cauchy sequence in $X$ is norm Cauchy.
It follows from Rosenthal's $l_{1}$-theorem that if a Banach space $X$ has the Schur property and contains no isomorphic copy of $l_{1}$, then $X$ is finite dimensional.

**Question**. Is there an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ such that $X^{*}$ has the Schur property and $X^{**}$ contains no isomorphic copies of $l_{1}$?

Thank you!

Comment: According to what you said, $X^*$ contains $\ell_1$, which obviously implies $X^{**}$ contains $\ell_1$ as well.

Comment: I do not know $X^{**}$ would contain $l_{1}$ whenever $X^{*}$ contains $l_{1}$. Could you give a detailed proof ?

Comment: @DongyangChen If a Banach space $Y$ contains a copy of $\ell^1$, then $Y^{*}$ contains a copy of the space of measures $M([0,1]) = C([0,1]) ^{*}$, which contains a copy of $\ell^1([0,1])$. This was proven by Pełczyński, see Proposition 3.3 in https:/doi.org/10.4064/sm-30-2-231-246

Comment: A particular case of Pełczyński's result can also be found in Corollary A in https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.03057v1.

Comment: Thanks, Narutaka and Onur. You are right.

Comment: This is related to the first comment made by Narutaka; any separable Banach space can be embedded inside $\ell_\infty$.